# itunes2rhythm python3 script returns syntax error

Tags: sound, python

I am trying to execute this script with Python3

- [itunes2rhythm](https://github.com/guillier/itunes2rhythm)

Using this command:

`python3 /media/trunk/SOUNDS/itunes/itunes2rhythm-master/itunes2rhythm.py`

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/media/trunk/SOUNDS/itunes/itunes2rhythm-master/itunes2rhythm.py", line 285, in <module>
exec(open(sys.argv[0][:-2]+"conf").read(), cfg)
File "<string>", line 20
iLib=""/media/trunk/SOUNDS/itunes/Library.xml""
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could someone explain what needs to be done to execute this script properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just edit your `itunes2rhythm.conf` file to remove the extra quotes:

iLib=""/media/trunk/SOUNDS/itunes/Library.xml""

It should be:

iLib="/media/trunk/SOUNDS/itunes/Library.xml"

in order to `exec` this line with Python.

Comment: that really helped, i think im almost there, but got another error:

Unknown drive: localhost/C:

Comment: wait i see it now inside the lybrary XML file. there are a few occurances. How should I modify these?

Comment: I think you have to modify the driveMapping value of your config file as well

Comment: I have done the drive mapping in the config file, the problem is that now i am getting endless errors because all the links inside the Library file point to old destinations. do I have to manually type each one of those out?

Comment: May I suggest to start a new question including the content of both your xml and the config file? You can use http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ to copy those files and just give the links in your next question.

Comment: ok here is the new thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/437105/itunes2rhythm-python3-script-errors